# How to set multiple cell styles to one cell apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to add multiple cellStyles for a cell , but the last cellstyle is overwriting the existing cell style.How to add both the cellstyles??

...

```
CellStyle numberStyle = Workbook.createCellStyle();
 DataFormat numberFormat = Workbook.createDataFormat();
 numberStyle.setDataFormat(numberFormat.getFormat("0.00;[Red]0.00"));


CellStyle dollarStyle= Workbook.createCellStyle();
DataFormat dollarFormat = Workbook.createDataFormat();
dollarStyle.setDataFormat(dollarFormat.getFormat("$#,#0.00"));

cell5.setCellStyle(numberStyle);
cell5.setCellStyle(dollarStyle);
```

...

Comment: I tried this but didn't work        

~~~                                                                       

CellStyle combined = pWorkbook.createCellStyle();
combined.cloneStyleFrom(dollarStyle);
combined.setDataFormat(numberStyle.getDataFormat());
cell5.setCellStyle(combined);
~~~

Comment: A cell can only have one cell style. And a cell style can only have one number format. Seems you want `...getFormat("$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00")`?